# Win 2k3 - DNS query?

Tags: networking, dns, windows-server-2003

I'm learning about network and I configured DNS in 2k3. 
In forward zone : cntt.edu > www.cntt.edu [ 192.168.188.4 ] .

[ All IP / DNS configuration is right ]

After that I use wireshark to catch packet when I enter www.cntt.edu in IE . I see there's no DNS here, I forward directly to 192.168.188.4, there's no query .
Any problem ?

Thanks for reading this :)

Comment: Did you clear the local DNS cache before looking up the name?

Comment: I remember I deleted this one before. The problem is I query in DNS server, so it forwards directly . Thanks Fred :)

Answer (score 0):

2 possible reasons for this:

1) you have a cached DNS entry/hosts entry/lmhosts entry etc...

2) the forwarding query is executed by the DNS server, not the client - you request an IP, DNS does everything else until you get an IP/failure back.